# SSAS - Changing Target Server

Tags: ssas, bids

I am new to analysis services and data cubes.  I inherited someone else's project, and I am using BIDS 2005.  The company I work for recently relocated my analysis database to another server--lets say from "Server1\tst1" to "Server2\tst1".  Now every time I reopen BIDS and want to deploy my data cube to the new server, I have to go Project -> Properties -> Deployment -> and modify the target server value to deploy to the new location.

How do I change the default deployment location value as to not recreate this issue everytime I open BIDS and deploy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The read/write attribute on the dwproj.user file was set to read only by source control.  Once read/write was available, the change in BIDS was retained each time the application reopens.